# How to get data from other table with Auth::user()->id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two tables: `Role` and `User`

### User

```
id
name
email
password
Roleid
```

### Role

```
id 
name
```

I want is to get name of `Role` for current logged in `User`. Something like `Auth::user()->role()->name;`

Comment: Please add an example of what you've tried and why it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on you define correct relation between roles and users table you should doing something like this:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$role = $user->role->name // Name of relation function in user model and gather all role data
```

if you dont define correct relation between users and roles you must do something like this:

in users table define a column named: role_id

and in users model doing:

```
public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }
```

and in roles model :

```
public function users() {
            return $this->HasMany(User::class);
        }
```

Comment: I want to show the role name of current logged in user on blade page using Auth::User()->id. I don't how to get data from role table. There is one to many relationship between these two table.

Comment: @AamirBashir if you define right relationship you can do this in blade: {{ auth()->user()->role->name }}

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$rolename   
   I am getting this error
this is my code
{{Auth::user()->role()->rolename}}

Comment: @AamirBashir Set the relation look like what i define in the answer

Comment: use `{{Auth::user()->role->rolename}}` not `{{Auth::user()->role()->rolename}}` ==> without ()

Comment: @AamirBashir You're welcome if it worked fine choose answer to best

Answer (score 1):

This is user model

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'username','name', 'email', 'password','loc_id','role_id','status'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\role', 'role_id');
}
```

}

this is role model

```
protected $table="role";
protected $fillable=['rolename',];

public function user() {
        return $this->HasMany('App\User');
    }
```

These two table have one to many relationship. Every user has a roleid by using this role id want to get the name of current loggedin user rolename from role table by using roleid(forgein key)
{{Auth::user()->role()->rolename}}
I am using this to get role name but getting an error.

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$rolename

Comment: you're roles table has column named rolename? or name? check it in fillable

Answer (score 0):

If you want only user id use this best way.

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
```

Otherwise need particular value,

```
$user_email = Auth::user()->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write this way:

```
{{Auth::user()->role->rolename}}
```

Don't add `()` with role